# Writing to multiple columns in a dataframe simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this code where I'm writing to multiple columns in a dataframe. Is there a way to simplify it so it happens in one line of code instead of the multiples lines?

```
tempSummary.at[name,'Wins'] = wins
tempSummary.at[name,'Singles'] = singles
tempSummary.at[name,'Doubles'] = dubs
tempSummary.at[name,'Triples'] = trips
tempSummary.at[name,'Quads'] = quads        
tempSummary.at[name,'Raw Score'] = rawScore
tempSummary.at[name,'Total Score'] = tempTotal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.loc` instead of `.at` which allows a list.

General solution:

```
df.loc[<row name>, [<list of col names>]] = [<list of vals>]
```

Your specific solution:

```
tempSummary.loc[name, ['Wins', 'Singles', 'Doubles', 'Triples', 'Quads', 'Raw Score', 'Total Score']] = [wins, singles, dubs, trips, quads, rawScore, tempTotal]
```

Anytime `.at` is used it is almost always better to use `.loc`